# When an Elixir Registry process restarts after crash, does it recover with registered keys?

Tags: elixir

According to Elixir [Registry documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html), if a registered process crashes, its keys are automatically removed from the registry.
When the Registry process itself crashes and restarted by a supervisor, does it recover with the registered processes' keys or it restarts afresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Registry process will "restart fresh". (as configured in its Supervisor)

Actually, all processes registered with a Registry are [link](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#link-1)'ed to the Registry process, [check this line](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/dbcc36ddb25782155cf6c7712019554b599b41d3/lib/elixir/lib/registry.ex#L816). Which means when a Registry crashes, all processes registered will also exit unless they specify other behaviours.

Comment: How to specify other behaviours?

Comment: @TangMonk When Processes are linked in Erlang/Elixir you can set the `trap_exit` flag, which will convert exit signals received by a process into normal messages, then you can handle it in `handle_info` etc.. see [this](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#flag/2) and [this](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#process_flag-2)

Answer (score 1):

The Registry process restarts afresh. Turns out it is easy to test with interactive Elixir.

```
# Create a Registry process and registers an Agent process.

{:ok, _} = Registry.start_link(keys: :unique, name: Registry.ViaTest)
name = {:via, Registry, {Registry.ViaTest, "agent"}}
{:ok, _} = Agent.start_link(fn -> 0 end, name: name)
iex(4)> Registry.lookup(Registry.ViaTest, "agent")
[{#PID<0.90.0>, nil}]

# Kill Registry process

iex(7)> Process.exit(Process.whereis(Registry.ViaTest), :kill)
** (EXIT from #PID<0.84.0>) evaluator process exited with reason: killed

Interactive Elixir (1.5.0) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> 
15:20:42.180 [error] GenServer Registry.ViaTest.PIDPartition0 terminating
** (stop) killed
Last message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.86.0>, :killed}
State: #Reference<0.2950178278.1828847617.245854>

nil

# Confirm the Registry process died
iex(2)> Process.whereis(Registry.ViaTest)                     
nil

# Restart the Registry process with the same name
iex(3)> {:ok, _} = Registry.start_link(keys: :unique, name: Registry.ViaTest)
{:ok, #PID<0.100.0>}

# Look up previously registered Agent process
iex(4)> Registry.lookup(Registry.ViaTest, "agent")                           
[]
```